# Сходимость в нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

[image: График обучения]

Насколько знаю, ситуация, когда ошибка "застывает" на одном уровне (как на изображении), говорит о плохой сходимости в сети. Является ли это серьезной проблемой и изменение каких параметров может это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ситуация, когда ошибка "застывает" на одном уровне (как на изображении), говорит о плохой сходимости в сети

Это не всегда так. Зависит от того, на какую точность Вы претендуете. В Вашем случае, это, судя по всему, нормально и связано с архитектурой сети. Как видно из Вашего графика нейронка подошла вплотную к качеству работы на тестовом множестве.

При обучении следует ставить критерий остановки НС и по ошибке, и по числу итераций:

```
while abs(err_i - err_{i+1}) < eps or epoch < 30:
    pass
```

Я полагаю, что Ваша модель не сходится далее, так как для данной архитектуры сети и метода обучения это предел. Приведу пример. Перцептрон Розенблатта, как ни крути, не сможет разделить два нелинейных класса. Т.е. он не сможет построить разделяющую поверхность в виде параболы. Он всегда будет строить её в виде прямой.

Если Вы хотите получать лучшее качество, то Вам необходимо изменить спсоб обучения, либо архитектуру сети. Замечу, что для вышеупомянутого перцептрона, как бы Вы не меняли обучение, результат не изменится. Это происходит в связи с тем, что обучение -- это метод деформации разделяющей гиперплоскости. В таком случае, если есть два класса, которые разделены параболой, то как Вы бы ни крутили прямую, разделить классы не получится.

И не забывайте про переобучение. Для борьбы с этим эффектом часто используют регуляризацию.

Comment: Еще для нелинейной разделимости можно использовать ядерный SVM, причем он меньше подвержен переобучению чем нейронные сети.

Comment: @Merlin Ядерный SVM пригоден для меньшего класса задач. Для него нужно хорошо подготовить данные. Более того, не на каждом датасете он сработает как нужно. Кроме того, SVM, как правило, используется для классификации.

Comment: Почти любые данные данные нужно подготавливать, не забываем про принцип  «Мусор на входе — мусор на выходе».